# replacing a background image with particle ground?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this sweet particle system which can be found [HERE](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/).

I'm basically trying to replace a background image with this particle system but unfortunately the particles will sit above my navbar filling the screen, then I have to scroll for my website content. below is a photo of my index page for a visual representation. (I'm using a template with most the content not filled in so please don't judge the wording :P)

[image]

The code for the content as seen here:

```
<div class="bg">

        <div id="home" class="header wow bounceInDown" >
                <div class="top-header">
                    <div class="container">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" title="dreams" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <!----start-top-nav---->
                     <nav class="top-nav">
                        <ul class="top-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#services" class="scroll">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#port" class="scroll">FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about" class="scroll">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="loginNew.php">Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#" id="pull"><img src="images/menu-icon.png" title="menu" /></a>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!----- //End-header---->
        <!---- banner ---->
        <div class="banner wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.8s">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="banner-info text-center">

                    <h1>Smart trading for the smarter investor.</h1><br />
                    <span> </span>
                    <p>We are a digital agency that believes in building things that are  meaningful!</p>
                    
                    <div class="contact-right wow fadeInLeft">
                        <form class="test" action="indexNew.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                            <p class="borders">Sign Up For Crypto Pals</p>
                            <input type="text" required class="text" name='user_name' placeholder="Username...">
                            <input type="email" required class="text" name='email' placeholder="Email...">
                            <input type="password" required class="text" name='password' placeholder="Password...">
                            <input class="wow shake" data-wow-delay="0.3s" type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="register" />
                        </form>

                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <a class="account" href="loginNew.php">Already have an account? Sign In.</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

so the `<div class="bg">` has this CSS:

```
.bg{
    background:url(../images/baner.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

I've tried to simply add the `particles` class to my `<div class="big">` but that drops down the entire site and still displays the particles above it.

I really hope I put in enough info.
Thanks

Comment: create a working demo

Comment: The particle div needs to be absolutely positioned for it not to affect other elements. Either that or use z-index stacking. https://jsfiddle.net/5meyqn1v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have a background image anymore and just replace it with the particles, you can base off the [CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/VincentGarreau/pen/pnlso) available from the README on the author's Github.

Then all you need to do is add all of your code below it and change the `#particles-js` `z-index` to negative:

```
#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  z-index: -3;
}
```

Here's a working [CodePen](https://codepen.io/aska-g/pen/MOjmXe). I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little modification on a css file removed background color & add background image. Go to the js file at the bottom remove background colour hope it helps:

```
code here:
#particles-js{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: ;
background-image: url(tt.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Here is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ee0Z.jpg)